# How to retrieve the data from firebase JSON using JavaScript for each one of object

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my JSON and Code which gives only array but not it values. As I had used push it generating Unique Id from, which I am not getting. All the values that stored in that id.

```
{
  "nitin" : [ {
    "mobile" : {
      "-K7GalDi5aAahDENCRi" : {
        "name" : "file:///D:/Software%20Drive/addItem.html?category=mobile",
        "price" : 345,
        "quantity" : 34
      }
    },
    "perfume" : {
      "-K7K7HSu4rQNwbH3ud0H" : {
        "name" : file:///D:/Software%20Drive/addItem.html?category=perfume",
        "price" : 1000,
        "quantity" : 20
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

This is my code

```
  fbref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var newPost = snapshot.val();
      console.log(newPost);
      fbref.on("child_added", function(newPost,pre){
          newchild=newPost.val();
          console.log(newchild); 
          var n=newPost.key();
          console.log("this is key"+n);
          console.log("Name"+newchild.name);
          console.log("Price"+newchild.price);
          console.log("Quantity"+newchild.quantity);
      });  
  });
```

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/ab11b7h6/

Answer (score 2):

The `child_added` event will fire when a child node is added *directly* under the location that you're querying.

So if you're querying the root of the JSON you show, a `child_added` will fire for `nitin`. And then if we'd add `puf`, a `child_added` will fire for that too.

```
{
  "nitin" : [ {
    ...
  }],
  "puf": [ {
    ...
  }],
}
```

If you want to receive a `child_added` for items inside `mobile` or `perfume`, you will need to attach a `child_added` on the parent node of those:

```
fbref.child('nitin').child(0).child('mobile').on('child_added'...
```

Or:

```
fbref.child('nitin/0/mobile').on('child_added'...
```

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/menilu/edit?js,console) for a working sample of this.

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen  but this procedure is done by me. What I want is how to go for next  object that is perfume. Again I have create a new variable as suggestion given by you, but it should check that automatically whether any more node are existing or not and display that node

Comment: How to get enter in perfume, mobile.... and get their keys under them and to display them. Also let me know how to create the indexes of array to increment so that I can avoid of that  unique keys genereated by push and get the data using purely array based but not id.

Comment: "avoid of that unique keys generated by push and get the data using purely array based but not id" -> there's a reason Firebase recommends against using array indices: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase